# Memory leak when using sqlite3 with C++

Tags: c++, string, sqlite, memory-leaks, stringstream

The program writes into SQLite database, the messages are received through a wireless module. But somehow there is a memory leak every time a message is received and written to the database, after about 10 000 writes the program is using 1GB of memory.

The documentation for [SQLite3 with C++](https://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html) says that memory leaks are prevented with `sqlite3_finalize()` and `sqlite3_close()` which are present:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include "sqlite3.h"

using namespace std;

#define DB "test.db"
sqlite3 *dbfile;

bool connectDB();
void disonnectDB();
int insOrUpdate(string s);
int select(string s);

struct messageStruct_t {
  float value;
};

bool isOpenDB = false;

int main() {
  int counter = 0;
  while (1) {
    int header = 1;
    int message = rand() % 3;

    if (message) {
      counter ++;

      switch (header) {

      case 1: {
        messageStruct_t recMessage;
        recMessage.value = 55;
        int receivedSendersID = 2;

        //SQL query to get foreign key
        stringstream strm_select;
        strm_select << "SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE sendersID="
                    << receivedSendersID;
        string s_select = strm_select.str();
        cout << "SQL query: " << s_select << endl;
        int sendersID = select(s_select);
        cout << "Sender's ID: " << sendersID << endl;


        if (sendersID == 0) {
          cout << "Error: Sender doesn't exist\n";
        } else {
          stringstream strm_insert;
          strm_insert << "INSERT into table2(id,value,sender_id) values("
                      << counter << ", "
                      << recMessage.value << ", " << sendersID << ")";
          string s_insert = strm_insert.str();
          cout << "SQL query: " << s_insert << endl;
          insOrUpdate(s_insert);
          cout << "Recorded data: " << recMessage.value << endl;
        }
      }

      default: {
        break;
      }

      }
    }
  }
}

bool connectDB () {
  if (sqlite3_open(DB, &dbfile) == SQLITE_OK) {
    isOpenDB = true;
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void disonnectDB () {
  if ( isOpenDB == true ) {
    sqlite3_close(dbfile);
  }
}

int insOrUpdate(string s) {
  if (!connectDB()) {
    return 0;
  }

  char *str = &s[0];
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  int result;
  const char *query = str;

  if (sqlite3_prepare(dbfile, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    result = sqlite3_step(statement);
    //the documentation says that this destroys the statement and prevents memory leaks
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    return result;
  }
  //and this destroys the db object and prevents memory leaks
  disonnectDB();
  return 0;
}

int select(string s) {
  if (!connectDB()) {
    return 0;
  }

  char *str = &s[0];
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  const char *query = str;
  string returned;
  if (sqlite3_prepare(dbfile, query, -1, &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) {
    int ctotal = sqlite3_column_count(statement);
    int res = 0;

    while (1) {
      res = sqlite3_step(statement);
      if (res == SQLITE_ROW) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ctotal; i++) {
          string s = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement, i);
          cout << s << " ";
          returned = s;
        }
        cout << endl;
      }
      if (res == SQLITE_DONE || res == SQLITE_ERROR) {
        cout << "done " << endl;
        break;
      }
    }
  } else {
    cout << "Can't prepare" << endl;
    return 0;
  }
  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  disonnectDB();

  int result;
  stringstream convert(returned);
  if (!(convert >> result)) {
    result = 0;
  }

  return result;
}
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
sendersID INTEGER,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
CREATE TABLE table2 (
id INTEGER NOT NULL,
value FLOAT,
sender_id INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(sender_id) REFERENCES table1 (id)
);

INSERT INTO table1(sendersID) values(2);
```

Comment: Please reduce the sample to something that can be compiled an run. Currently I would need to invent `message`, `headerStruct`, `header` and `recMessage` to even compile it, hoping that the actual error is in fact in the code you pasted and not in one of the parts you did choose not to paste....

Comment: I modified the code to compile. I am pretty sure that the leak is there because the memory used by the application doesn't grow while the program is not receiving messages.

Comment: @Rumburak, I added a test database. The memory leak is here, 300MB after 4 000 writes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your connectDB(..) call , you don't check if the database is already open before opening it again. Your memory leak is probably from the repeated mappings of this database into your memory space.

There may be other issues with this program but the change below to connectDB(..) should help with the leak on every successful insert.

```
bool connectDB() {
    if (false == isOpenDB && sqlite3_open(DB, &dbfile) == SQLITE_OK) {
        isOpenDB = true;
    }
    return isOpenDB;
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Just a remark: disconnectDb does not reset isOpenDB, so this won't actually help. And isOpenDB would not be required if dbfile were initialized to nullptr and reset to nullptr in the disconnect. That why I suggested to use RAII. It is cleaner and easier to grok anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use RAII for your connections and also for your statements. There are several places where you return early without cleaning up statements and/or closing the connection.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, I will look into it.